# Programmatically retrieving a drop down box selection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Using VS 2012, c#, asp.net web form

Trying to create a calculator with a drop down box that determines the operator(/*-+) for two text box values.

The drop down box is called DropDownList1. I novice with C, only done some java. My question is, how do i check what operator has been selected via the drop down.

I have tried the following

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (DropDownList1 = * //or whatever ( obviously won't work for obvious reasons        {

           Then add textbox1 and textbox2 values
           }
            if (-)//and so on
            etc...
```

Although the textboxes would be strings so I have no idea how to actually add the two values after I crack the drop down box :S)

I also tried to grab it via a list index of some sort? But i wasn't sure of the syntax however I tried stuff like

```
 DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = something? // Wasn't sure where I was going here either
```

Any help would be great.

PS I wanted to use a drop down box even though it's silly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just do:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value
```

To get the value of the selected dropdown and then you can just do a case statement on what to do with the selected operator.

```
switch(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
 {
    case "+": 
        // do +
        break;
    case "-"
        // do -
        break;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean selecteditem and thanks this is what I was looking for

Comment: Yea I was just typing fast from memory

Comment: Add a check of null before checking your values.

`if(DropDownList1.SelectedItem !=null)
 {
     switch(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)
     {
        case "+": 
            // do +
            break;
        case "-"
            // do -
            break;
    }
 }`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Equals("your item value here"))
```

or

```
if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.Equals("your item text here"))
```